# str.contains in pandas with if statement, python

Tags: python, pandas

this is simple question but i don't know why i cannot compare if corectly.

```
df:

A,B
1,marta
2,adam1
3,kama
4,mike
```

i want to print 'exist' if specific name exist in df

for example, i want to check if marta exist in df['B']

code:

```
string='www\marta2'
if df['B'].str.contains(string,regex=False).all()==True:
    print('exist')
else:
    print('not exist')
```

when i am using `.bool()` instead of `all()` i am receiving error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I am reveiving False on each line, why ? should i compare this type of string some how in different way?

EDIT:
I need to use `IF` statement because in my code instead of `print` my code need to assigh variables, normaly i would use different way.
If my `string='marta'` it works well but with additional string not

EDIT:

```
new code:
string='www\marta2'
    if df['B'].str.rfind(string).any():
        print('exist')
    else:
        print('not exist')
but it compares everything, so even if one letter is in column it will print 'exist'
```

Comment: Your problem is that `'marta'` does not contain `'www\marta2'`. This: `string='mart'; print(df['B'].str.contains(string,regex=False).any())` does print `True`...

Comment: You can see in my answer the loop will terminate if the value is found. You need not have to go through the elements further, if the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check if the string exists at all in the whole df, use `any()` instead of `all()`.

If you want to check if the string exists for each row, you can create a new column and don't have to use if statement

```
df.loc[df['B'].str.contains(string,regex=False), 'C'] = 'exist'
df.loc[~(df['B'].str.contains(string,regex=False)), 'C'] = 'not exist'
```

EDIT: I tried this and it works as long as the string is exactly what you're looking for.

```
string='www\marta2'
if df['name'].str.contains(string,regex=False).any():
    print('exist')
else:
    print('not exist')
```

Comment: hey,. please see my edits, i need to use IF anyway, becasue id True my var=1 or 0 in my real code

Comment: Can you give me a few example of what your strings look like? It might be a problem to be solved with regex

Comment: my string looks same as in my example var string

Comment: is that the exact string you're looking for in the dataframe? Please see my EDIT

Comment: i need to check if this specific string exist in specific column, i dont need to choose rows

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you:

```
>>> for b in df["B"].values:
...     if string.rfind(b) != -1:
...         print("exists")
...         break
...
```

The looping which is `for` loop includes `df["B"].values` which returns array values of column `B`. Now if you have the array you can loop through it and thus get the output.
In the condition `if` statement, I have just compared each of the values of the `B` column. `rfind()` given the output of the partially matched string output or substring.
It thus the magic.

Comment: interesting way, could you explain it ? its working for me

Comment: @sygneto I have added the explanation to the answer. please check if you got it. Accept the answer if it helps you can also upvote answers here. It encourages who answers.

Comment: @sygneto Thank you for your upvote. If the answer is helpful then please accept it.

Comment: is there any option to avoid for loop?

Comment: @sygneto What is the issue with for loop? Ultimately you have to loop through the elements right?

Comment: the problem is that i am receiving answer for each row in dataframe, i need to know only one answer if this string exist in column or not. my code works good but only when string is excacly the same as in column

Comment: @sygneto But my answer satisfies your question. You have not mentioned anything in the question or given a sample of the data you are looking for. What you have suggested is what I have tried on my side.

Comment: @sygneto I guess I have truncated the loop with the `break` statement if you can see.

Comment: rfind function in this case wont work because it will print 'exist' even when only one letter is the same. i will try different approach to modify this string,

Answer (score 0):

answer on my question:
to recive only one answer if string exist or not in column, good way is to use `df.str.contains()`, as we know str.contains is comparing only whole string, that's why my first code doesn't work.
second way is to use `rfind` but it will be always true because this function is comparing single letters in my case.

the answer is to prepare string that i am comparing to receive expected result

```
string='www\marta2'
new_string=string.split('\\')[-1][0:5]
if df['B'].str.contains(new_string,regex=False).any():
    print('exist')
else:
    print('not exist')
```